# Which files should be imported in react tsx if we are using SASS?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass, react-typescript

I am a bit confused with using `SASS/SCSS` in a react typescript project. I found an article saying how `SASS/SCSS` can be used in react project: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet
Although it seems importing `.scss` files in `.tsx` component files works perfectly fine, like this:

```
import './component-1.scss';
```

but then what about building the `scss` files and compiling them to `css`? why do we need that if a browser can understand the `scss` files. or am I understanding wrong here?
if compiling `scss` files are necessary and we should import `compiled css` files in the component like:

```
import './component-1.css';
```

then how will I achieve this prior to compile because there will only be scss files present in the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser doesn't understand SCSS. When your application is built, the SCSS is converted to CSS. Those SCSS file imports basically get transpiled into your application to importing regular old CSS, which the browser then uses.

The code in your source files is *not* indicative of what the output of your build process looks like. In the same way that we can write our React files using JSX, but that's converted into regular old JS when we build the app, because the browser doesn't understand JSX.

Comment: In such case, what should be imported in the .tsx files?

Comment: Assuming your transpiling of SCSS to CSS is part of the build process of your application, then your source code should import the SCSS file

Comment: If I use webpack and compile the scss files to css, the build of the react project will contain css file or scss file content? and which files should be uploaded to server then?

Comment: If you use `create-react-app` then it *might* already be handled for you, but if you have your own custom webpack setup then you need a loader for SCSS files. This loader will take the SCSS files you `import` and add the compiled CSS to the built application. This is the common one: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/

Answer (score 2):

The practice is that we use CSS preprocessors like SASS or LESS to ease the development process. browsers do not understand them. we have two ways to compile them into CSS files:

- Using task runners like `Gulp` and `Grunt` or bundlers like `Webpack`(with proper loaders).
- Compile them by hand using software like `Koala`(not recommended in development process)

if you are using Webpack or other bundlers, all you have to do is to import sass files, add proper loader(sass-loader in case of Webpack), and let Webpack do the rest for you. Webpack will take care of compiling and bundling.

Comment: I understand that, but what should I import in my tsx files then if I compile the scss to store the css in separate directory?

Comment: as I mentioned above, it's all about how your build process works, if you are using a bundler the bundled compiled css will go in dist or build folder after build.